# Google Sheets Function Autofill

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a solution to a problem that seems minor at first, but if you end up having spreadsheets with 1000's of rows, it involves a lot of dragging. I need an autofill for a formula for a column that pulls information from the first sheet.

Here is what I have so far.

```
=if(SUMPRODUCT(--(Magento!A2:A<>""))=0,"",Magento!A2)
```

I suppose I could do the same thing with =(Magento!A2).. but I was trying to get it to detect and auto-fill based on what is input into the first sheet.

Basically, if there are 29 SKUs in the first sheet which is the master, I'd like it to populate the information in the second sheet. At the same time if there ended up being 2000 skus on the first sheet, I'd like the 2000 skus to be populated on the second sheet column A without having to drag and drag the autofill.

Comment: Google Sheets or Excel? You mention Sheets but you originally had the Excel tag.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't mean to put the excel tag

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/ringshopifytestformula-uploadtomagento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you just want to bring in a copy of whatever is in Magento!A2:A, exchanging any zeros for nulls. If that is the case:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(Magento!A2:A=0,,Magento!A2:A))
```

If that isn't what you had in mind, please share a *direct* link to your sheet (or a copy of it), using **File > Share**.

**Addendum (after comment clarification)**

You just needed this:

`=ArrayFormula(Magento!A2:A)`

Comment: I shared the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dlCyFVQLBy39nKZZOxBaNKJQmnw03tUKrcbIS_r_wFY/edit?usp=sharing

I only want sheet Upload To Magento column A to fill automatically IF there is something entered in Magento sheet column A.

Comment: Erik definitely helped out, the easiest answer was that I was making everything too complicated. 

=ArrayFormula(Magento!A2:A)

Was the quick answer!